# Redux-Thunk "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Creating my store with Thunk middleware

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(
    reducer, 
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

And creating my action which calls a promise

```
export function getArticle(url) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    fetchArticle(url).then( 
      article => dispatch(setArticle(article)),
    );
  };
}

function fetchArticle(url) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    request
     .get(url)
     .end( (err, res) => {
       if (err || !res.ok) {
         reject('Oh no! error');
       } else {
         resolve(res.body);
       }
     });

  }) 
}

export function setArticle(article){
  return {
    type: constants.SET_ARTICLE,
    article
  }
}
```

In my article component I am calling dispatch on `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.dispatch(
    getArticle('http://api.example.com/')
  );
}
```

But getting error: "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.".

What is wrong with this setup? I have tried calling `compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))` but to no avail.

Comment: It may sound dumb but make sure you have redux-thunk installed, `npm install redux-thunk`.

console.log `thunk` to make sure that exists.  

Your code looks fine, it just seems like thunk is not registering.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok except that it's missing how to handle errors (promise rejection). Your api might be returning errors and you're not handling it which could result to that error message.

Try adding

```
export function getArticle(url) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    fetchArticle(url)
      .then(article => dispatch(setArticle(article)))
      .catch(err => dispatch({ type: 'SOME_ERROR', err }));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return function (dispatch) {
    fetchArticle(url).then( 
      article => dispatch(setArticle(article)),
    );
  };
```

To

```
return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchArticle(url).then( 
      article => dispatch(setArticle(article)),
    );
  };
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
export function getArticle(url) {
    return fetchArticle(url).then( 
      article => dispatch(setArticle(article)),
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Redux every action must return an object.

You may use:

```
export const getArticle= url=> dispatch => {
 fetchArticle(url)
   .then(res =>
     dispatch({ type: SET_ARTICLE, payload: res.data })
   )
   .catch(err =>
     dispatch({
       type: GET_ERRORS,
       payload: err.response.data
     })
   );
};
```